# How do I declare a const size_t inside a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm trying to use C++ arrays in my class:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
    private:
        const size_t NCOL = 4;
        array<int, NCOL> row;

    public:
        Test(){}
        ~Test(){}
};  

int main() {
    Test t;
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error messages and I don't know why:

```
test.cpp:9:14: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Test::NCOL’
   array<int, NCOL> row;
              ^~~~

test.cpp:8:23: note: declared here
   const size_t NCOL = 4;
                       ^

test.cpp:9:14: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Test::NCOL’
   array<int, NCOL> row;
              ^~~~

test.cpp:8:23: note: declared here
   const size_t NCOL = 4;
                       ^

test.cpp:9:14: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Test::NCOL’
   array<int, NCOL> row;
              ^~~~

test.cpp:8:23: note: declared here
   const size_t NCOL = 4;
                       ^

test.cpp:9:18: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   array<int, NCOL> row;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You want both `const` and `static`.  This isn't C#.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there in the error messages:

> invalid use of **non-static data member**  ‘Test::NCOL’

`NCOL` is not `static`, so it is a data member of every instance of `Test`, and gets its value at runtime when `Test` is constructed.  You can't use runtime data values in template parameters.

Make `NCOL` be `static` instead, then the compiler can use it as a compile-time constant like you are intending it to be:

```
static const size_t NCOL = 4;
```